# Check if a stored procedure has a specified parameter with a SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a chance to find all stored procedures which have a specified parameter `x`?

In my belief (pseudo code):

```
select * from master where objectType = 'storedprocedure' and parameter='x'
```

Where are the meta information about the stored procs stored (in the master database)?

I have to use Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards, patrick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view that you could use is `PARAMETERS`. This query will list all stored procedures that have such a parameter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.SPECIFIC_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS p
WHERE p.PARAMETER_NAME = '@x'
```

Answer (score 4):

For sql server 2005+, if you need script for 2000 - note it in the question

```
   IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.procedures pr
        JOIN sys.parameters pa
            ON pr.object_id = pa.object_id
        WHERE 
            pr.object_id = object_ID('dbo.ProcName')
        AND pa.name = '@paramName'
    )
        PRINT 'Exists!'
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks also for your help! I'm using  ms sql 2005.